# rsync not respecting permissions and ownership with cwrsync

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -avzd --owner=john --group=www-data  --chmod=ug=rwX,o=rX  -e "ssh -p 45"  /cygdrive/e/test  john@www.mydomain.com:/var/vhost/locals/test
```

This is driving me mad.. if anyone can offer a possible route to solution i would be extremely grateful.

I am setting up some developers working environments, windows to debian using cwrsync

The above rsync command is being triggered in a macro after file save.

It all works perfectly well with the exception of the permissions; the result is:

```
perms owner group
0644  john  john
```

Is it possible to set the permissions to the following with an rsync command?
    perms owner group
    0755  john  www-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i gave up.. i could not find a way for the files to land in the destination as john:www-data

As a work around, for the vhost running these files i forced apache to run as john:www-data

This worked fine:

```
[...]
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId john www-data
</IfModule>
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact same issue. But I think your approach opens up a security issue where apache now potentially can write to any file in the www folder

Comment: Would you be able to expand a little please? Only the vhost is running as john:www-data, how might this result in your concern?  Thanks, John.